# Slope of a line

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction, geometry

Just a quick question. Is there a fast inbuilt function to calculate the slope of a line segment passing through two points `{p11,p12}` and `{p21,p22}`? Something like

```
slope[l_] := (l[[2, 2]] - l[[1, 2]])/(l[[2, 1]] - l[[1, 1]])
```

where `l` is a list of the form `{{p11,p12},{p21,p22}}`. If not, any faster way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

slope1[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)

slope2[l_] := 1/(Divide @@ Subtract @@ l)

slope3[l_] := Divide @@ Reverse@(Subtract @@ l)

With[{l = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}},
 slope1@l == slope2@l == slope3@l // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
slope[l_] := Tan[Apply[ArcTan, l[[2]] - l[[1]]] ]
```

For example

```
slope[{{0,0},{1,1}}]
(* 1*)
```